# JQuery mouseover with duplicate id

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#tiros").mouseover(function() { $("#hello").css('display',''); });
$("#hello").mouseover(function() { $("#hello").css('display',''); });
$("#hello").mouseout(function() { $("#hello").css('display','NONE'); });
 });
</script>

<link href="../css/tablas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body >
<div align="center">
    <style type="text/css"> 
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>

  <table id="tablas"  border="0">
    <caption id="titulo"> DISTRIBUCION DE MAQUINA SM74    <tr>
      <td><table  id="tablas" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td id="cabezera">07-06-2013</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
          <td> <div align="right" id="tiros">20000</div>
           <div id="hello" style="display:NONE;position:absolute; z-index:1; ">
        <ul>
      <li id="Subtitulo">Nº OT: 19178</li>
      <li id="Subtitulo">Tipo: P</li>
      <li id="Subtitulo">Sucursal: ANTOFAGASTA</li>
      <li id="Subtitulo">Detalle: PEGABLE</li>
      <li id="Subtitulo">Cliente: ASOC. I</li>
    </ul>
    </div></td>
          </tr>
              </table></td>
      <td><table  id="tablas" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td id="cabezera">08-06-2013</td>
          </tr>
               <tr>
          <td> <div align="right" id="tiros">20000</div>
           <div id="hello" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:1;">
        <ul>
      <li>Nº OT: 19178</li>
      <li>Tipo: P</li>
      <li>Sucursal: ANTOFAGASTA</li>
      <li>Detalle: PEGABLE</li>
      <li>Cliente: ASOC. I</li>
    </ul>
    </div></td>
          </tr>
                </table>
      </td>
      <td><table  id="tablas" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td id="cabezera">09-06-2013</td>
          </tr>
              </table></td>
      <td><table id="tablas"  border="1">
        <tr>
          <td id="cabezera">10-06-2013</td>
          </tr>
              </table></td>
      <td><table  id="tablas" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td id="cabezera">11-06-2013</td>
          </tr>
              </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**When I put the mouse over the div, the first div works and the other does not, the value of the id is "tiros" for all de divs and i call with the function mouseover and works only inf the first dive. Hep and sorry for my English**
:)

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique. Please check out the relevant HTML specification section - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: You should not duplicate ID attribute. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321702/multiple-id-selector-in-different-scopes

Comment: You're better off using classes and then proceed with a toggleClass().

Comment: this is a php impresion ,a loop of a While in mysql_fetch_array..

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id` tag with multiple of the same value to a class. Then change the selector in your jQuery function for what you wish to do to `.` instead of `#`.

So it would be `$(".tiros").mouseover(function() { $(".hello").css('display',''); });` instead of `$("#tiros").mouseover(function() { $("#hello").css('display',''); });`, and you would make that change for the other functions where you're calling an `id` with multiple instances.